# Designing a Word Index Database

Tags: mysql, indexing, lookup, keyword

I have a approx 1000000 pages, to index, which I need to find the closest page for a set of keywords.

My current thinking is to create a string for each page which included the significant words, along with the number of occurrences. So each row would be (Page Id, Keyword) -Unique Index, and Occurrences

Then when I'm doing a lookup, I should be able to search for each word and create a score.

My concern is that the table could easily be millions of rows, and I'm not sure how easily it would be to find a page that concerns 5 keywords to generate the score.

Has anybody got any suggestions to improve the plan, to make it quicker and less intensive to use.

Comment: how many significant words per page?  this could be doable in mysql, but it is the kind of thing people use specialized full text search software for.  mysql's full text indexing is an option for that.  but you need to look at how well a solution maps to your exact use cases

Comment: The material is very varied some will have 100+ significant words,wome will have 3 or 4 words, I was hopping by breaking the content in to keywords, the indexing would be much easier/quicker searches etc.

Comment: if you just want to find multiple keywords, I would do it like https://dbfiddle.uk/aaDLYgTO   if you want a score based on multiple keywords, not all of which have to appear, depends on the details of your words and how you want score calculated.  using a mysql fulltext index might be appropriate or might not.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT title FROM fti WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+windows +query +linux' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| title                                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows     |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fti WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('windows query linux' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    18758 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT title FROM fti WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('windows query linux' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 11;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| title                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Connecting from PHP on one linux box to another linux running MySQL     |
| Re: Connecting from PHP on one linux box to another linux running MySQL |
| export hebrew from linux to windows                                     |
| Performance on Linux vs Windows                                         |
| Backup Transfer from Windows Mysql to Linux Mysql                       |
| Re: Performance on Linux vs Windows                                     |
| Copy specific tables from windows to Linux                              |
| Re: Copy specific tables from windows to Linux                          |
| From Linux to Windows                                                   |
| Different results on Linux and windows                                  |
| Re: Different results on Linux and windows                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT title, MATCH(title) AGAINST('windows query linux') AS score FROM fti WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+windows +query +linux') LIMIT 11;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| title                                                                    | score              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| Connecting from PHP on one linux box to another linux running MySQL      | 13.917098999023438 |
| Re: Connecting from PHP on one linux box to another linux running MySQL  | 13.917098999023438 |
| Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows     | 12.674331665039062 |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows | 12.674331665039062 |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows | 12.674331665039062 |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows | 12.674331665039062 |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows | 12.674331665039062 |
| Re: Same Mysql Update query giving different result in linux and windows | 12.674331665039062 |
| export hebrew from linux to windows                                      | 11.582389831542969 |
| Performance on Linux vs Windows                                          | 11.582389831542969 |
| Re: Performance on Linux vs Windows                                      | 11.582389831542969 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
11 rows in set (0.04 sec)


mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fti;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   185079 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

**Summary**

- MySQL's `FULLTEXT` is fast.
- My table is 18% of the size of yours, but even finding 10% of the rows was fast.
- There are variations (`BOOLEAN`, `NATURAL LANGUAGE`, with/awithout `+`, etc).
- You need the `MATCH` in both the `SELECT` and the `WHERE` to see the numbers and have it sorted by "relevancy".
- The Index declaration was simply `FULLTEXT KEY` title `(`title`),`; `title` could be a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`.